# Splitting a persons full name over three columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I was wondering if someone could please help me figure out how to split a person's full name over three columns (forename, middle_name, surname) in a pandas DataFrame?

Below, is a sample of the column I am trying to separate.  Any help would be much appreciated.

name
Abakanowicz, Magdalena
Abbey, Edwin Austin
Abbott, Berenice
Abbott, Lemuel Francis
Abrahams, Ivor
Absalon
Abts, Tomma
Acconci, Vito
Ackling, Roger

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Yes I agree with Vico, If the answer is too simple we might post the code but on the long run we need to see your effort on solving the problem. Not a good practice to expect answers without showing your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split with rename if `name` is your column name i.e

```
names = {0:'first name',1:'middle name',2:'last name'}
df['name'].str.split(' ',expand=True).rename(columns = names).fillna('')
```

Output :

```
   first name middle name last name
0  Abakanowicz                      
1    Magdalena       Abbey          
2        Edwin      Austin    Abbott
3     Berenice      Abbott          
4       Lemuel     Francis  Abrahams
5         Ivor     Absalon      Abts
6        Tomma     Acconci          
7         Vito     Ackling          
8        Roger
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `name`:

```
df[['sur','nam1','nam2']] = df.pop('name').str.split(r',\s+|\s+', expand=True)
print (df)
           sur       nam1     nam2
0  Abakanowicz  Magdalena     None
1        Abbey      Edwin   Austin
2       Abbott   Berenice     None
3       Abbott     Lemuel  Francis
4     Abrahams       Ivor     None
5      Absalon       None     None
6         Abts      Tomma     None
7      Acconci       Vito     None
8      Ackling      Roger     None
```

Or:

```
df[['sur','nam']] = df.pop('name').str.split(', ', expand=True)
df[['nam1','nam2']] = df.pop('nam').str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
           sur       nam1     nam2
0  Abakanowicz  Magdalena     None
1        Abbey      Edwin   Austin
2       Abbott   Berenice     None
3       Abbott     Lemuel  Francis
4     Abrahams       Ivor     None
5      Absalon       None     None
6         Abts      Tomma     None
7      Acconci       Vito     None
8      Ackling      Roger     None
```

Comment: Sir I think he meant name as column name not a string in the dataframe column.

Comment: Yes, it is colum name ;)